# Add detailed help for Stack Snippets to the editor's "Code" section and the advanced help

Tags: feature-request, answers, asking-questions, help-center, stack-snippets

Stack Snippets are markedly under-documented. Please update the "Code" section of the help you get when you click the (?) icon in the editor, as well as the advanced help, to provide detailed instructions for creating Stack Snippets, perhaps drawing from answers [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support).

Comment: Cross-site dupe (MSO): [Add information on Stack Snippets to Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277340/add-information-on-stack-snippets-to-help-center)